# How can I export database structure from the db into migration file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-task

Is there a way to export database structure in the database from the rails application?
I believe there is a way to export Data from the db using rake.

`rake db:migrate` will create tables from migration files. Is there a command that does opposite way so that migration files will be generated from the db?

I have previously built a rails application during 3.0.x version.

I have many more migration files than the actual number of tables in the database because I have some migration file which adds and removes or change the column structure of the database.

Obviously, I can manually change each migration file and change it into migration file with 3.1 standard, but I just want to know if there is a way to export data base structure.
(Or, deriving from existing schema file)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use command `rake db:schema:dump`, it will do it for you

Edit:
You might be interested in this link:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-rake.htm

Comment: That worked :P Thanks!, so its my task to split the file into different migration files?

Comment: No. You can "load" the schema directly with rake too. Then you can migrate any changes since you dumped the schema.

Comment: Pavling's right.  You'd use rake db:schema:load to load it up.

Answer (score -1):

After rake db:schema:dump you can use a gem called schema_to_scaffold to generate a scaffold script.
it outputs: rails g scaffold users fname:string lname:string bdate:date email:string encrypted_password:string
from your schema.rb our your renamed schema.rb. Check [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/schema_to_scaffold)